Flutter Web: firebase auth using phone number getting captcha issue
I'm using firebase authentication using phone number. I have added my number for testing which works fine and even I can see captcha verifier for same. But if I try with another phone number I'm getting error below

[firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired.

Code:
  Future<ConfirmationResult> authViaPhoneNo({
    required String phoneNo,
  }) async {
    return auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNo);
  }

  Future<User?> verifyOTP({
    required ConfirmationResult result,
    required String otp,
  }) async {
    final credential = await result.confirm(otp);
    return credential.user;
  }
}

Also If i use with captacha
 final captchaVerifier = RecaptchaVerifier(
     container: 'recaptcha',
     size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
     theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
     auth: FirebaseAuthPlatform.instance,
 );

I'm getting this error
DartError: Assertion failed: file:///Users/user-name/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.12.0/lib/src/firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart:94:9
web.window.document.getElementById(container) != null
"An exception was thrown whilst creating a RecaptchaVerifier instance. No DOM element with an ID of recaptcha could be found."


did you used international phone format or not!!

Yes i did test adding ISD Code also with adding format mentioned in example

did you try refreshing the page before trying with new phone number?

Yes i did and clear the cache data

You may need to add reCAPTCHA configuration for your sign in method as mentioned in the documentation Phone Authentication

web.window.document.getElementById(container) != null
"An exception was thrown whilst creating a RecaptchaVerifier instance. No DOM element with an ID of
recaptcha could be found."

UA:
Виглядає так наче ви не підключили капчу до свого проекта firebase. Ця проблема в мене пропала після того як я в Google cloud додав reCAPTCHA Enterprise API скопіював ключ і додав в App Check > Apps > Register далі скролите бачите reCAPTCHA, обираєте і вносите ключ. Після цього все має запрацювати
EN:
It looks like you haven't connected the captcha to your firebase project. This problem disappeared for me after I added reCAPTCHA Enterprise API to the Google cloud, copied the key and go into App Check > Apps > Register, then scroll to see reCAPTCHA, select and enter the key. After that, everything should work
